# Repeat the same regression by group in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat

Let's imagine that I have 50 imputed datasets for the mtcars dataset (although it has no missing data). My model looks like this:

```
model <- with(implist, lmer(mpg~disp+hp+(1|gear))
```

I want to repeat this by cyl. Although there are a few categories in this dataset, I have more than 50 groups in my real dataset.

I have tried tidyverse, but it seems like tidyverse isn't compatible with "with" function.

Comment: Try `lapply(implist, \(x) with(x, lmer(mpg~disp+hp+(1|gear))))` Or can be `fmla <- mpg~disp+hp+(1|gear);lapply(implist, lmer, formula = fmla)`

Comment: If you need a group by approach (assuming `implist` is a list of dat.frames). `library(purrr);library(dplyr);map(implist, ~ .x %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(out = list(lmer(fmla, data = cur_data()))))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. I tried your way but it led to <lmrMdLmt> instead of the estimates when using map. With the approach with lapply, it led to each result for the imputed datasets not for the groups.